# javascript why I could not get the name of file from files array?

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload

I have simple javescript about input|file object:

```
  var upfiles=new Array();

  function addfile(files){
      upfiles.push(files);
      alert(upfiles[0].name);  //undefined
      alert(files[0].name);    //can get file name
      upfiles[0].prop("name"); //can get file name
      alert(upfiles.length);    //1
  }
```

I don't know why the `upfiles[0].name` only give me return undefined, while the `upfiles[i]).prop("name")` work. the different between two method?

Comment: because `upfiles` is an array of arrays

Comment: place files structure here, but yes, it looks like files is array of file

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
upfiles[0][0]
```

Seeing as you push an array of files into another array etc.

Comment: That does'nt really matter. `files` is an array of files, even if it contains only one file, so when pushing `files` into a `new array`, you have an array inside an array and you have to refference it twice like above.

Comment: but the upfiles[0].prop("name"); work that mean it should be one dimensional array, if it is 2 it should be upfiles[0][0].prop("name");

Comment: prop is a jQuery method for getting properties from elements, and it working with your array is just a fluke, not an intended function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `concat` rather than `push` here, to create a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Yes, but I just add only one file. so I am sure it should be one dimensional array

Comment: If it's always one file, then you should use `push(files[0])`, since `files` is an array, and you want to push the item in the array, not the array itself. In your specific scenario of always one item in the array, `push(files[0])` would have the same effect as `concat`.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I can just comment...

I'd try this in chrome, and put

```
console.log(upfiles);
```

before your alerts... And just examine the structure of the object in the console.
When I worked with a framework that doesn't have detailed documentation, I had to examine their function outputs like that a lot.